# Is that a good usage of the decorator pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

I have to write 2 text files for a customer. The files contain information from our DB. Our app is being used by many customers and thus not both files will be written for every customer. Some just get the first file and some also the 2nd. The file structure differs from customer to customer, thats why I made an abstract class with an abstract method *Write* and a specific class for each customer which iverrides the Write method. Thats for the first file which is for all customers, just with different content and structure.

```
abstract class CustomerWriter
{
    //...
    abstract Write();
    //...  
}
```

Then I have 2 classes which inherit from that. Thats fine I guess. Now for the second file which only needs to be written for some of the customers ... is it a good idea to use the decorator pattern here and decorate the class for the first file? Its not the same base class (CustomerWriter). I am not sure if this is too much for my case, thats why I am asking.

How would I decorate the specific class for the first file?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about you register all allowed file writers based on the customer configuration somewhere and then you execute all the writers which are registered?

**Update**: You could use an IoC container for that but a simple

```
public class FileWriterRegistry
{
   public void Register(CustomerWriter writer)
   {
   }

   public void WriteAllFiles()
   {
       ... call Write() for each registered writer
   }
}
```

might do.

Comment: Might do, but I added above that for the 2nd file I have anoher base class ... its not a CustomerWriter.

Comment: But it gave me an idea...I could do this just for the second. It would be nice if this was configurable in my config file...is there a common way to do this?

Comment: Well, is there a reason why your writer for the second file has a different base class? Is the 2nd conceptually different? If you need another base class (for whatever reason) then you might consider introducing a ICustomerWriter interface for all your writers. As for the config file: I don't think that there is THE common way of doing it. If you use an IoC container then those usually support some kind of xml configuration but you might just add some settings your config in order to select all applicable writers.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot refactor the second writer to share a common base class or interface, you may actually want to use the adapter pattern. You could write an adapter which makes the second writer appear to be a CustomerWriter. That way your clients can use one common base class or interface (even better). Then you can use an IoC container to be able to configure which instance the clients instantiate.

The adapter would look something like this:

```
public SecondWriterAdapter : CustomerWriter
{
    private SecondWriter writerInstance;
    public SecondWriterAdapter(SecondWriter writerInstance)
    {
        this.writerInstance = writerInstance;
    }

    public override void Write()
    {
        writerInstance.someExistingWriteMethod();
    } 
}
```